# Vue.extend() + TypeScript = methods must specify event: MouseEvent, how can I avoid it?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

Please see this minimum example

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    text: String,
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      console.log(this.text); // Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Vue'.Vetur(2339)
    },
  },
});
```

However, if I specify event type, things went normal

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    text: String,
  },
  methods: {
    click(event: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(this.text); // Everything is fine right now!
    },
  },
});
```

But this leads to another problem, I don't need to use the `event` parameter for my component.

Although I can wright `click(_: MouseEvent)`, but it leads to unclear code.

How can I avoid typing event?

Answer (score 0):

Please define props like this and retry

```
props: {
   text: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
   }
}
```

Comment: Not solved the problem, I think it's vetur's problem, although vetur is yelling, build doesn't output any type error